# Can't select nodes in XML document

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml

My XML document is the **Corpus.xml** file in the [TEI XML Brown Corpus](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/packages/corpora/brown_tei.zip)

I want to select every `s` node in the document, so I can iterate over them and extract data.

The problem is that no matter which method I try, I cannot select the `s` nodes! I've tried:

- `xml.Root.Descendants("s")`
- `xml.Root.XPathSelectElements("s")`
- `XPathDocument`

But nothing works. I get no errors. The result returned is an empty set!

Comment: There is no `BrownCorpus.xml` file that i can see? How about posting a small complete sample?

Comment: This usually indicates that you are missing a namespace manager or your xpath is wrong.

Comment: I've corrected the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML documents has namespace declared:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<teiCorpus xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
           xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <!-- content -->
</teiCorpus>
```

So you should use `XNamespace` to select elements:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
var elements = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "s");
```

Take a look on [Working with XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx) for further information.